# How can i parse the specific strings from every 20 links but only the first and last links?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count(); i++)
                {
                    string pathDateTime = urls[0].Substring(48, 12);
                    string pathDateTimeLast = urls[urls.Count - 1].Substring(48, 12);
                    var d = DateTime.ParseExact(pathDateTime, "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    var e = DateTime.ParseExact(pathDateTimeLast, "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    string path = countriesMainPath + "[" + d + "---" + e + "]";
                }
```

In this case i have 780 links in urls.
I want to parse the link in index 0 and in index 19
Then the links in index 20 and 39 then index 40 and 59.

Every 20 links but to parse only the first and last not all the 20 links.
So in path i will have the parsed index 0 and index 19
Next time in path the parsed index 20 and 39
And so on until the end.

Comment: Something with `Skip` and `Take` would be where I start

Comment: You are saying Index , so how about using something like arrays ? I dont know whether c# have them or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a counter and increment it by 19 every iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count(); i++)
{
    // Do your stuff
    i = i + 19;
}
```

On your next iteration, you will start at index 20.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that in your code you actually means to use the  data from the first and last of each 20 index block and that the code parses the strings properly, you could use a for loop something like this:

```
List<string> paths = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count(); i += 20)
{
    string pathDateTime = urls[i].Substring(48, 12);
    string pathDateTimeLast = urls[i + 19].Substring(48, 12);
    var d = DateTime.ParseExact(pathDateTime, "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var e = DateTime.ParseExact(pathDateTimeLast, "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    paths.Add($"{countriesMainPath}[{d}---{e}]");
}
```